# How to use two OneDrives?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

OS in my desktop is Windows 10. And OneDrive is in-built application in Windows 10.

If I use OneDrive in desktop computer or To use OneDrive in desktop computer, I need to sign in my desktop with Microsoft Account.

I have to use two OneDrive accounts in my Windows 10 Desktop Computer without using Microsoft Account for sign in desktop. Please let me know, how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft recently within the last 6 months added this to the OneDrive client for Windows 10.

1. Right Click on the OneDrive taskbar icon
   [image]
2. Select **Settings**

   [image]
3. Click **Add an Account**

   [image]
4. Log-in into the desired account

   [image]
5. Done

Microsoft OneDrive:

[image]

> I have to use two OneDrive accounts in my Windows 10 Desktop Computer
>   without using Microsoft Account for sign in desktop. Please let me
>   know, how to do this?

After I performed some additional researched.  It does appear that it is no longer a requirement, to link your Microsoft Account, to your local account in order to use OneDrive on Windows 10.  You can simply link your accounts here:

[image]

Comment: I should point out this answer assumes you have linked your account to a Microsoft Account.  If that truly is a "do not pass go do not collect $200" requirement then you have no other choice but to use a third-party client.

Comment: I have placed a bounty on this question, since my answer apparently is not helpful, so perhaps the person who issued the down vote on my answer, is willing to submit a helpful answer.

Comment: I would like to know how I can improve this answer.  If you don't feel it answers the author's question, I would like to know, so I can simply remove an answer that isn't helpful.

Comment: The last part is untrue, I have had both my school's OneDrive and my personal using the same OneDrive program, I refuse to use OneDrive for business as GROVE.EXE (OneDrive for Business) would not stay closed on my last install of Windows 10

Comment: My research says otherwise.  OneDrive requires you link your local account to your MS account.  However,  OneDrive for Business, will allow you to avoid that.  Post your own answer, with proof, that says something else.  Be specific on how the author achieves their goals

Comment: I know as I had been  using the normal OneDrive program for both for about 3 months BEFORE I even installed Office365 on Windows 7, then I immediatly installed and used it on Windows 10, and recently I reinstalled Windows 10, Still working with the normal program

Comment: and I will NOT make a new answer as It would be nearly Identical to yours, just without the ending note

Comment: I am leaving the comment to cover my rear, because I can't prove it to myself, that it isn't true.

Comment: [Here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AnmM1KBLLjaMhkh2OzP-z60vgViI) is a link to screenshots using the snipping tool in order of when taken, personal account on left, business account on right, the 4th is when I open the `OneDrive for Business` app, witch was the first time I have on this install, and all the pictures were taken on the same install.

Comment: The pictures should be enough proof, if you need any more, tell me

Comment: @DanHolli -  I am going to assume, you don't have your local account linked to your Microsoft Account, but I have updated my answer.

Comment: I do, I added a picture to the folder linked before named `Account.PNG` showing that my account Is linked(censoring personal info and picture of course), ad It is required for me, as I'm using it for Insider Preview

Comment: @DanHolli - I think we talked over each other heads when it came to that last statement.  It was there because, without being connected to a MS Account, I don't believe you can sync an account with OneDrive.  I do believe it possible if you use OneDrive for Business though.

Comment: I'll test if 2 normal OneDrive accounts will sync with it now

Comment: I just tested, it, you cannot have 2 personal accounts, but you can have 1 personal and 1 business account

Answer (score 4):

You could map both your OneDrive Files folders to network shares on your computer, so you could directly access both.
I admit that I don't know how well this will work with two OneDrive logins
(see remarks below).

The following is adapted from the article
[How to Map OneDrive as a Network Drive to See All Your Files](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/map-onedrive-network-drive).

1. Use your browser to log into `onedrive.live.com`.
2. Right-click on `Files` in the left-pane, and then click Copy link location (Firefox), Copy link address (Chrome) or Copy shortcut (Internet Explorer). This will copy to the clipboard the URL to `Files`.
3. Open Notepad and paste the URL that you have copied in the above step. Select and copy the digits and letters following the `cid=` parameter (stop selecting before hitting a `#` or `&` character).
4. In Windows Explorer, go to This PC.
5. Click on the `Computer` tab then `Map network drive`.
6. In the `Folder` field, enter `https://d.docs.live.net/` followed by the CID you copied above.
7. Check the `Connect using different credentials` box.

[image]

8. Click `Finish` and enter your OneDrive login.

[image]

Remark: Here is the part I don't know when mapping from two OneDrive accounts,
whether it is a good idea to check the `Remember my credentials` box when
connecting. You will have to try and see, and in case of a problem
disconnect the mapped drive and try again.

Comment: Each mapped folder should save individual credentials, so I'd select Remember. And in case of a problem disconnect the mapped drive and try again.

Answer (score -3):

1. You can sign to your browser and add delete files.
2. Use a virtal machine with VirtualBox or VMware Player
3. Downgrade your Widnows.